# LoadingCache expireAfterWrite not working as expected

Tags: java, guava, google-guava-cache

I am having a Loading Cache like this :

```
MyCacheLoader loader=new MyCacheLoader();
MyRemovalListener listener=new MyRemovalListener();
LoadingCache<String, String> myCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                .concurrencyLevel(10)
                .weakKeys()
                .maximumSize(2)
                .expireAfterWrite(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .removalListener(listener)
                .build(loader);
```

But when I do something like this to test :

```
System.out.println(myCache.get("100"));
System.out.println(myCache.get("103"));
System.out.println(myCache.get("110"));
System.out.println(myCache).get("111"));
Thread.sleep(230000);
System.out.println(myCache.size());
```

Am still getting 2 and not zero. Why ? After more than 120 seconds I should have got zero size if am not wrong ?

**MyCacheLoader**

```
public class MyCacheLoader extends CacheLoader<String,String>     {
    @Override
    public String load(String key) throws Exception {
        return key;
    }
}
```

**MyRemovalListener**

```
public class MyRemovalListener implements RemovalListener<String,String> {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyRemovalListener.class);
    @Override
    public void onRemoval(RemovalNotification<String, String> removalNotification) {
        logger.info("Message with message Id ("+
                removalNotification.getKey()+ ") is removed.");
        System.out.println("Message with message Id ("+
                removalNotification.getKey()+ ") is removed.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

First, if you are new to Guava's Cache API or if you are treating it as if it implements the `Map<K, V>` interface then I recommend reading [CachesExplained · google/guava Wiki](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained). "A `Cache` is similar to `ConcurrentMap`, but not quite the same."

e.g. [`Cache.size()`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html#size()) "returns the *approximate* number of entries in this cache" (*emphasis* added) unlike [`Map.size()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#size--) which "returns the number of key-value mappings in this map."

As such, we should not expect `Cache.size()` to return an *exact* number of entries but an *approximate* one. I would not generally make assertions on `Cache.size()` although I certainly would on `Map.size()`.

Second, "caches built with `CacheBuilder` do *not* perform cleanup and evict values 'automatically,' or instantly after a value expires, or anything of the sort. Instead, it performs small amounts of maintenance during write operations, or during occasional read operations if writes are rare" ([When Does Cleanup Happen? · CachesExplained · google/guava Wiki](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained#when-does-cleanup-happen)).

Consider the following example:

```
LoadingCache<String, String> myCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .concurrencyLevel(10)
        .weakKeys()
        .maximumSize(2)
        .expireAfterWrite(120, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .removalListener(notification ->
                System.out.println(notification.getKey() + " removed"))
        .build(new CacheLoader<String, String>() {
            @Override
            public String load(String key) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("loading " + key);
                return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            }
        });
myCache.get("100");
myCache.get("103");
myCache.get("110");
myCache.get("111");
Thread.sleep(230);
System.out.println(myCache.size());
myCache.get("111");
System.out.println(myCache.size());
```

Ouptut:

```
loading 100
loading 103
loading 110
100 removed
loading 111
103 removed
2
110 removed
111 removed
loading 111
1
```

As you can see, evictions here do not occur until items are read from the cache.

For more details along with a more detailed example see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39252714/3255152) to [How does timed cache expiry work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39250083/3255152)

Comment: I want to do something when the current cache size has reached MAX BUFFER SIZE and do something else, if it hasn't reached. Then how this can be achieved in this case ? Because, acc to this, It will not give exact size and also once max size is reached then it wont clean.

Comment: Depending on the cache implementation, you might be able to use [`Cache.cleanUp()`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/11.0.1/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html#cleanUp\(\)). `CacheBuilder` can return different implementations depending on how you use it and could return different implementations for different Guava versions so you'll need to test this whenever you change your cache configuration and/or Guava version.